# Decoherence model of two qubits interacting with correlated multimode fields - open quantum system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, phase-space, open-quantum-systems

I read paper on open quantum system, that talk about non-Markovian process and memory effects.
they described the system as a generic decoherence model of two qubits interacting with correlated multimode fields.

when they described the interaction and the evolution in time, they say that the unitary U work like this:

$U_i(t)|0>=\otimes|\eta>=|0>\otimes\otimes_kD(-\xi_k(t_i))|\eta>$

$U_i(t)|0>=\otimes|\eta>=|0>\otimes\otimes_kD(-\xi_k(t_i))|\eta>$

in this part, the $\eta$ is new and they didn't talk or explain about him.
after this, they talk about the initial state, that is:

$|\psi(0)>=|\psi$<sub>12</sub>$>$$\otimes|\eta$<sub>12</sub>$>$

I try to find what $\eta$ is symbol and understand what is it.
Is there something that $\eta$ usually represents?

I'm afraid that in general I don't exactly understand the description of the system and therefore I don't understand what $\eta$ is.
If someone can tell me if there is any phrase that usually refer to $\eta$?

and also, maybe clarify this setup and describe more details about "a generic decoherence model of two qubits interacting with correlated multimode fields.", that would be excellent.

I attached a [link](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.108.210402) for this paper.

Comment: It seems like the state $| \eta \rangle$ is some arbitrary state, but I agree that this is not remotely clear from the paper and it shouldn't have made it past referees. I don't know of a standard meaning to $\eta$ in this literature, but that could be ignorance on my part. I don't think anything in that paper is "generic" but is contrived to achieve some particular outcome.

Comment: Also you should use \langle and \rangle for bras and kets, respectively, i.e., $\left| \psi \right\rangle$.